# Boyd & Vandenberghe's proof that all simplexes are polyhedra.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

On page 33 of [B&V's convex optimization book](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), during the proof that any simplex can be represented as a polyhedron, they discuss a $n \times k$ matrix $B$ with full column rank and conclude that:

> Therefore there exists a nonsingular matrix $A = (A_1, A_2) \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ such that
>   $$ AB = \begin{bmatrix} A_1\\ A_2 \end{bmatrix} \;\; B = \begin{bmatrix} I\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

This seems strange given the definition of $A$, and I can't find any reason from the text that B should have that structure, and from a later equation it appears that what they intended to say was:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1\\ A_2 \end{bmatrix} \;\; AB = \begin{bmatrix} I\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
though this is not currently in [the errata](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/cvxbook_errata.html).

My questions are:

- Am I correct that this is indeed a mistake? If not, what am I misunderstanding?
- If it is, can $A$ be constructed by simply taking $A_1$ as any left inverse of $B$ and the rows of $A_2$ as any basis of the null space of $B^\intercal$? Would that guarantee that $A$ is nonsingular?